# MongoDB: Aggregate with nested $group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
 db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'type': 'energy'
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10000
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            day: {
                $dateToString: {
                    date: "$when.date",
                    format: "%d/%m/%Y"
                }
            },
            sensor: "$id"
        }, 
    }, 
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            sensor: 1,
            when: 1,
            value: 1,
            day: 1
        }
    },    
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$day",
            data: {
                $push: "$$ROOT"
            },

        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            'data': 1
        }
    }
])
```

Which returns this data format:

```
 {
    "_id" : "05/04/2018",
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac66be9b02d5c18fd4106c7"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-05T13:53:22.703-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1522947202,
                "milli" : 1522947202703
            },
            "day" : "05/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen3"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac66be9b02d5c18fd4106c8"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-05T13:53:22.705-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1522947202,
                "milli" : 1522947202705
            },
            "day" : "05/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen4"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "06/04/2018",
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac7e5d2efe88a4e76c008d2"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-06T18:25:38.885-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1523049938,
                "milli" : 1523049938885
            },
            "day" : "06/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen3"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac7e5e4efe88a4e76c008d5"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-06T18:25:56.105-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1523049956,
                "milli" : 1523049956105
            },
            "day" : "06/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen3"
       }
    ]
},
```

...

Note that we have in each "data" document, different types of sensors (sen3, sen4, ... ,senN).

I'm trying to aggregate this result once more, agrouping the data by sensor, to get the output something like this:

```
  {
    "_id" : "05/04/2018",
    "sen3" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac66be9b02d5c18fd4106c7"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-05T13:53:22.703-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1522947202,
                "milli" : 1522947202703
            },
            "day" : "05/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen3"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac66be9b02d5c18fd4106c7"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-05T13:53:22.703-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1522947202,
                "milli" : 1522947202703
            },
            "day" : "05/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen3"
        }
    ],
    "sen4" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac66be9b02d5c18fd4106c8"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-05T13:53:22.705-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1522947202,
                "milli" : 1522947202705
            },
            "day" : "05/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen4"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac66be9b02d5c18fd4106c8"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-05T13:53:22.705-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1522947202,
                "milli" : 1522947202705
            },
            "day" : "05/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen4"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "06/04/2018",
    "sen3" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac7e5d2efe88a4e76c008d2"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-06T18:25:38.885-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1523049938,
                "milli" : 1523049938885
            },
            "day" : "06/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen3"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac7e5e4efe88a4e76c008d5"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-06T18:25:56.105-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1523049956,
                "milli" : 1523049956105
            },
            "day" : "06/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen3"
        }
    ],
    "sen4": [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac7e7a7efe88a4e76c008de"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-06T18:33:27.365-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1523050407,
                "milli" : 1523050407365
            },
            "day" : "06/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen4"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ac7e7a7efe88a4e76c008de"),
            "value" : 0,
            "when" : {
                "date" : ISODate("2018-04-06T18:33:27.365-03:00"),
                "unix" : 1523050407,
                "milli" : 1523050407365
            },
            "day" : "06/04/2018",
            "sensor" : "sen4"
        }
    ]
}
```

**In short:** I want to group the data in *days*, *sensors* and inside each *sensor* the results that belongs with that day and sensor.

I'm trying to create a nested `$group` but in all tentatives it goes wrong.

Is this possible to do and case yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "type": "energy" }},
  { "$limit": 10000 },
  { "$addFields": {
    "day": { "$dateToString": { "date": "$when.date", "format": "%d/%m/%Y" }},
    "sensor": "$id"
  }}, 
  { "$project": { "_id": 1, "sensor": 1, "when": 1, "value": 1, "day": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "day": "$day", "sensor": "$sensor" },
    "data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "day": "$_id.day" },
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id.sensor", "v": "$data" }}
  }},
  { "$addFields": { "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }}},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": [ "$_id", "$data" ] }}}
])
```

Comment: It resolves the problem beautifully. But the output gives me no order by date (day) or sensor. When i add a {$sort: {'day': 1}} at the end, it order by the first element of the string day, not by the date. Is there a way to make it properly? Thx man!

Comment: with which day you want to `$sort`? Inside the `sen` array?

Comment: I just wanna sort by the day element outside the sen array. Anyway, this implementation is enough. Thank you!